# I can't connect to Firebase because Gradle not supported by bintray-release plugin

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bintray

I got this warning in my Gradle Build tab

> Warning:Gradle 3.3 not supported by bintray-release plugin. Update required!

but I have the last release as in Android Developers page [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) and I also have the last release of bintray library.!

my build.gradle (Project):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.5.0'
   }
```

here's the error in Gradle Console:

```
**************************************
WARNING: Gradle 3.3 not supported by bintray-release plugin. Update required!

The bintray-release plugin doesn't support version of Gradle below 3.4 for Android libraries. Please upgrade to Gradle 3.4 or later.
The last bintray-release plugin supporting Gradle 3.3 is 'com.novoda:bintray-release:4.0'

Upgrade Gradle:
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 3.5 --distribution-type all

The bintray-release plugin can't create a Publication for your Android Library with Gradle 3.3!
**************************************
```

if I try to change gradle to `2.3.4` or `2.3.+` it didn't work.!
I can't connet to my firebase because of this issue, it keeps showing me this error when trying to connect with Firebase:

> Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.`

Comment: You mixed up the version number of the android plugin (which Google has called "gradle" to confuse people) with the version of Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

That error message isn't asking you to upgrade your buildscript dependencies.  It's asking you to upgrade your version of Gradle that you use to build your app.

Did you try running the command it suggested?

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 3.5 --distribution-type all
```

The latest version of Gradle as of this moment is actually 4.0.1, so you could try that as well.  The end result is to get your Gradle distribution changed in your project's `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file.